# Too many Partitions on drive, can't dual boot ubuntu alongside win8 on Thinkpad

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad S431 with Windows 8. It has a 128gb SSD, and My partitions are WINRE_DRV, Windows8_OS, Lenovo_Recovery, 7gb Hibernation Partition. I also have allocated 20gb for Ubuntu.

When I tried to install Ubuntu, it told me that I have too many OS's on the machine, and the new partition I created is labeled "unusable".

What can I do?

Edit: Volume type is MBR.

I have deleted an unnecessary windows 8 partition from Gparted in the Try Ubuntu option. From there I have also formatted the drive to be ext4 on /dev/sda4 Now the problem is that Ubuntu will not install as "root file system is not detected"

I used ext2 as the filesystem for Ubuntu, and mount as '/'. This solved my problems!

Comment: I would start by editing your question to specify whether your disk is using an MBR or GUID style partition table. You can find this out in Windows 8 by going to Start/Control Panel/System and Security/Administrative Tools/Computer Management/Disk Management and then right in the bottom half of the screen right click on THE disk (not a partition), and choose properties. Under the volumes tab it will list a partition style.

Comment: I updated it with the volume type. I also added what I have done and the current problem that I am getting.

Comment: I assume that you deleted one of your partitions to get past the max 4 primary partitions on MBR systems? What type of partition did you make on the free space? Primary, or Extended?

Comment: The reason that I ask is that you will likely want a swap partition in which case you need an extended partition with 2 logical parititions. However this isn't the only way to handle the situation. Some people don't want swap at all because they have lots of ram, others prefer to use a swapfile. You partition type should be visible with Gparted.

Comment: Yep I deleted the Hibernation partition, as it is not needed for win8. I shrunk the main OS' partition and used that space and created an ext2 file system. Didn't bother with file swap though, only have 4gb of RAM on this laptop right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make extended partitions. A MS-DOS partition table allows a maximum of 4 primary partitions.

Don't try to shrink or split a primary partition in two that is located before the extended partitions because you may alter partition table.

> I also have allocated 20gb for Ubuntu.

Instead of allocating Ubuntu partitions from Windows, you should delete/shrink partitions to leave empty space in Windows. Then let Ubuntu partition manager create partitions on that empty space.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant I had done, I shrunk the win8 os partition , to use 20gb for ubuntu.

Comment: @FriarBob windows 8 partition is probably the second and is primary (not extended!). You must shrink an extended partition to be able to make another one and install Ubuntu. You can't have primary-primary-**extended**-primary...

Comment: So I went into try ubuntu and Gparted, I deleted the hibernation Primary drive (already had 4 primary partitions) as it is only there for win8 to have a quicker boot.

Comment: I shrunk my win8 partition and made a new one. Now it is telling me that there is no root file system detected. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

First look at, do all of them(partitions) work as primary partition. IF it is, use partition tool like 'gparted'or 3rd party tool to dis-select any of them who are not working as OS containing partition. This is because, primary partition is only be needed where a partition contain an OS.